Python не видит некоторые библиотеки в venv
Пишу код в VSCode. Создал проект с виртуальным окружением (venv). Через pip установил Flask. Но почему-то питон не видит эту библиотеку в venv'е. Как это можно исправить?
Разумеется я проверил пути PATH они в порядке


Также я пробывал пересоздавать виртуальную среду, ну и заодно переустановил VSCode и Python.
Впрочем он и другие некоторые библиотеки не видит как минимум Flet тоже, а вот colorama работает.
P.S Я пробывал использовать другую виртуальную среду.

Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками

Зачем вы указываете полный путь к системному питону, вы таким образом намеренно выключаете виртуальное окружение

В строке состояния VSCode есть выбор интерпретатора, который позволяет выбрать все доступные окружения. А стандартная кнопка Run редактора(или launcher неважно), автоматом запустит python.exe из виртуальной среды. Либо явно активировать среду и в следующей строке запускать файл без указания пути python my_file.py.

@AlexanderLonberg Спасибо за пояснение!

@Chaos_Sower хочу извиниться за использование скриншотов а также сказать спасибо за уточнение почему.

@andreymal я так и не понял как работают Системные переменные, так как пути указаны верно судя по других источниках информации, но я как ни будь копну глубже для понятия в будущем!
